# C# list of tasks and using task.whenAny performance

Tags: c#

I have 10 different methods with the same return type "List". I am adding all the methods to a Task. Iterate through the task list and execute them. I need to know which one is best for boosting up performance. Task.whenAny or Parallel.invoke?

Appreciate your responses.

Comment: It depends entirely on what your tasks are doing.  There may not be _any_ performance boost by running them in parallel, and indeed some things may get worse (eg if two tasks are both trying to access different areas of the same physical disk at the same time).

Comment: It could depend on the number of CPU's in your computer and the amount of memory in your computer.  Performance can be slow down considerably if there is a lot of page swapping between memory and swap space (on hard drive).  So increasing the number of parallel processes can increase the number of swaps if you don't have enough memory to support the parallel tasks.   Normally each CPU will have its own dedicated RAM so increasing CPUs increases RAM and usually reduces swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Task.WhenAll will wait for them all to complete in parallel.

Task.WhenAny will wait until the first one finishes.

Task.WhenAll is probably what you want and is good for performance too.